# Window 7 Task Scheduler Fails with 0x80 running MS Access Query

Tags: ms-access, scheduled-tasks

I have scheduled a task to run a .DAT file which opens and executes an MS Access macro then kills the MS Access task. The script is as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS" "\\net\group\sales.accdb" /x "Refresh - 03 - Refresh and Archive"
taskkill /f /im MSACCESS.EXE
```

Note this database file lives on a network drive.

When I run the script file (double clicking on it), the database opens, the query is executed, and MS Access closes. When I schedule the task as a test, the script executes and all is well.

The task is scheduled for 6:00 am. I am logged in to the computer when the task is run but the computer is locked. I have confirmed I have administrator rights and the administrator group has "batch job" priveledges. See [here](http://forums.techguy.org/windows-xp/878784-0x80-error-scheduled-tasks.html), [here](http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=7901&eventno=113&source=Schedule&phase=1), [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957131.aspx), and [here](http://www.brooksnet.com/faq/117-02.html) for references that I've found/followed. This seems to be the problem some folks face when getting this error. The task is set to run "whether user is logged in or not" in the options. I know the database is at least opening because the lock file (.LACCDB) is generated in the same directory and the last modified date and time is the date and time the task is scheduled.

Finally, I have a macro being run with the task scheduler on a different database which is run succesfully. This task has identical settings in the task properties and the .DAT file is the same as the task that is failing with 0x80.

Why is this task failing?

Comment: I followed your suggestion and have run into the same problem. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that my macro was attempting to read a text file while it was being written. This of course broke the macro.